# Python 2.7.13 does not respect NO_PROXY and makes urllib2.urlopen() error with "Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden"

Tags: python, ssl, urllib2, http-proxy, urlopen

The following test passes with Python 2.7.11:

```
def test_urllib(self):
    import urllib2
    import ssl
    context = ssl._create_unverified_context() # service does not have a trusted cert
    url = urllib2.urlopen("https://intranet.adress:port/", context=context)
    url.read()
```

After upgrade to Python 2.7.13 the test fails with:

> python/Lib/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
>       raise URLError(err)
>   URLError: urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden

I tried some header and proxy settings, but without any success. I get always the same error. What has changed between Python **2.7.11** and **2.7.13** in SSL authentication?

Answer (score 1):

PS.: Python bug created for this issue. no_proxy content starting with dot (.domain) broken in Python 2.7.13

https://bugs.python.org/issue29142

Comment: Summary based on above report; the bug was introduced in Python on 30th April 2016 and was fixed on 9th of January 2017. Effected versions: 2.7.12, 2.7.13, 3.5.2, 3.6.0. The fix should be included in the following versions: 2.7.14, 3.5.3, 3.6.1 and 3.7.0.